# Android , Unable retrieve ArrayList value of another class by passing an edit text value

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hi I'm a beginner in Android Programming..

[image: Here is the output I needed]

If I enter the letter "A" in edit text field it must display the corresponding ArrayList from another class on Button onClick.

I was searching the answer for two days here.. so pls don't mark it as duplicate..

This is my MainActivity.java file

```
package com.dve.jok3r.arrayretrive;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText enterLetter;
Button button1;
TextView arrayDisplay;

String getEnterLetter;

List<String> nameArrayMain;

ArrayMaker arrayMaker;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    enterLetter=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterLetter);
    button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    arrayDisplay=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.arrayDisplay);

    getEnterLetter=enterLetter.getText().toString();
    nameArrayMain= new ArrayList<>();

}

public void getArrayOnClick(View view) {

    arrayMaker=new ArrayMaker(getEnterLetter);

    nameArrayMain=arrayMaker.getNameArray();

    for (String object:nameArrayMain)
    {
        arrayDisplay.append(object+"\n");
    }


}
}
```

ArrayMaker.java

```
package com.dve.jok3r.arrayretrive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class ArrayMaker {

String getEnterLetter;

List<String> nameArray= new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayMaker(String getEnterLetter) {
    this.getEnterLetter = getEnterLetter;

    if (getEnterLetter.equals("A"))
    {
        nameArray.add("Arjun");
        nameArray.add("Anand");
        nameArray.add("Abhiram");
        nameArray.add("Aswin");
        nameArray.add("Abhishek");
        nameArray.add("Antony");

    }
    else if (getEnterLetter.equals("B"))
    {
        nameArray.add("Balu");
        nameArray.add("Balram");
        nameArray.add("Bheem");
        nameArray.add("Babu");
        nameArray.add("Basanth");
        nameArray.add("Boby");

    }
}

public List<String> getNameArray() {
    return nameArray;
}
}
```

When i Pass the string directly to the ArrayMaker class like this

```
arrayMaker=new ArrayMaker("A");
```

It returns the Araray list.
In this way I was able to get the result exactly as I needed ..

but when I pass the edit text string like this

```
getEnterLetter=enterLetter.getText().toString();
arrayMaker=new ArrayMaker(getEnterLetter);
```

It returns Nothing...

What Am I doing wrong here??

Should I use shared preferences or Intent ?

And is it the proper way to retrieve array list?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You have to add listview on view & pass Adapter to that list view. You can learn from this url :  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Actually I don't want to create a list item for each Array List elements.. All I wanted to do is displaying the Array elements into a text view separated by a new line . I am able to do that by passing the String "A" directly to the ArrayMaker Constructor and retrieve the corresponding array for the string. But not able to pass user input that I get from the edit text to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

For comparing two strings you dont use '==' in Java. You should use equals operator.

Here is your corrected ArrayMaker class:

```
public class ArrayMaker {
    String getEnterLetter;
    List<String> nameArray = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayMaker(String getEnterLetter) {
        this.getEnterLetter = getEnterLetter;
        if (getEnterLetter.equals("A")) {
            nameArray.add("Arjun");
            nameArray.add("Anand");
            nameArray.add("Abhiram");
            nameArray.add("Aswin");
            nameArray.add("Abhishek");
            nameArray.add("Antony");
        } else if (getEnterLetter.equals("B")) {
            nameArray.add("Balu");
            nameArray.add("Balram");
            nameArray.add("Bheem");
            nameArray.add("Babu");
            nameArray.add("Basanth");
            nameArray.add("Boby");
        }
    }

    public List<String> getNameArray() {
        return nameArray;
    }
}
```

For main Activity do something like this:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

   private Button button;
   private EditText editText;
   private List<String> nameArrayMain;

  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    editText=findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button=findViewById(R.id.getArrayButton);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ArrayMaker a=new ArrayMaker(editText.getText().toString());
            nameArrayMain=new ArrayList<>(a.getNameArray());
                      }
    });

    }



    }
```

Comment: Thank you, In MainActivity, if I pass arrayMaker=new ArrayMaker("A"); it works fine . But how to pass the user input string to the constructor ? getEnterLetter=enterLetter.getText().toString();
arrayMaker=new ArrayMaker(getEnterLetter); . It returns nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much.... Now it works fine !!! Unable to UpVote your answer .. I don't have 15 reputation ..